# Need to Sum results of a list created in PHP

Tags: php, list, sum

Okay I have list being populated and echoed out on a page

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `game_toe` WHERE `owner`='$mech_units'";
$mydata = mysql_query($sql);

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){

echo "<td>" . $record['upkeep'] . "</td>";
```

Now the results fluctuate depending on the number of 'mech_units' there are. What I need is to display the sum of the Upkeep of the units being displayed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sum the upkeep as you loop through the records using some kind of sum variable? `$sum=0; while (...) { $sum+=$record ['upkeep']; }` or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_sum](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) function

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `game_toe` WHERE `owner`='$mech_units'";
$mydata = mysql_query($sql);

$upkeep = []; // Empty array to store all retreived values

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){

    echo "<td>" . $row['upkeep'] . "</td>";

    $upkeep[] = $row['upkeep']; // Fill array with your values

}

echo array_sum($upkeep); // Now just coun array sum from temporary array
```

EDIT: I made some edit to fit your exact needs.